# Servlet won't to redirect after click on submit button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have code like this:

LoginServlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String username = request.getParameter("txtusername");
            String password = request.getParameter("txtpassword");
            if(username.equals("gogikole") && password.equals("1234"))
                {
                    response.sendRedirect("mainMenu.jsp");
                }
            //else
            //  {
            //      System.out.println("error");
            //  }
        }

    }
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="LoginServlet"></form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtusername"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="txtpassword"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="login"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I watched on Youtube this: [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0OfTZuIDcs)

and there everything works fine. I done everything like there, but when I click on submit button Login it won't to redirect me to mainMenu.jsp

For now, mainMenu.jsp just have welcome message.
How to redirect to main menu, if username and passwor are okey, after click on submit button?

Comment: Is this simply for experimentation, or are you trying to make something that will be used?

Comment: @chrylis It will be used for school project. This is just beginning. Why?

Comment: Because in real-world code, the answer is (1) not to write your own security code at all if you can help it (using something like Spring Security instead) and (2) not to simply hide your "real" URL behind a login redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.sendRedirect("mainMenu.jsp");
```

should edit like this：

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/mainMenu.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

> For now, mainMenu.jsp just have welcome message.

That can't be true if `mainMenu.jsp` is your welcome page. Possibly you missed to configure the same in `web.xml`.

*Option 1*: change file name `mainMenu.jsp` to `index.jsp`, same goes in servlet code for redirect.

**OR**

*Option 2*: change welcome file name in `web.xml`

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>mainMenu.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```